# How do I insert multiple value if there is only one value in form

Tags: mysql, arrays, for-loop, foreach, multiple-insert

I need to know how can I insert or update a value in my DB for a invoice form if the value of the input that I need to save is only one time?

I have a invoice form where I select a product in every row, and finally I have the input(user_id) with the value I need to save with the rest of the inputs

Like per example, I choose in the invoice:

```
10 tomatoes 
 5 garlics
 2 beans
```

and finally there is my Id ***(user_id, not the Id of PRODUCTOS table that is unique)***

```
Id=1
```

Here is the schema of my table, and how save or update until now:

```
| cantidad   | nombre del producto |   Id  | 
+------------+---------------------+-------+
|     10     |   Tomatoes          |     1 |
|      5     |   garlics           |     0 |
|      2     |   beans             |     0 |
```

Here what I need to save or update:

```
| cantidad   | nombre del producto |   Id  | 
+------------+---------------------+-------+
|     10     |   Tomatoes          |     1 |
|      5     |   garlics           |     1 |
|      2     |   beans             |     1 |
```

Here is the code:

```
            $conn->beginTransaction();
            $sql = "INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS
            (cantidad, nombreProd, Id)
             VALUES ";
            $insertQuery = array();
            $insertData = array();
            foreach ($_POST['cantidad'] as $i => $cantidad) {
                $insertQuery[] = '(?, ?, ?)';
                $insertData[] = $_POST['cantidad'][$i];
                $insertData[] = $_POST['nombreProd'][$i];
                $insertData[] = $_POST['Id'][$i];
            }
            if (!empty($insertQuery)) {
                $sql .= implode(', ', $insertQuery);
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute($insertData);
            }
            $conn->commit();
```

Thank you

Comment: `update yourtable set id=1`? id fields are usually unique per-record, so not sure what you're trying to get al...

Comment: @MarcB The `id` is for `userid` and not the `id` of `PRODUCTOS` TABLE that is unique, I need this for register which user added "x" invoice or updated "X" invoice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a single userID you want to INSERT for each product record. I can probably provide a better answer if you post the output of `print_r($_POST)`, but basically in your `foreach $POST` loop, keep the user ID static:

```
foreach ($_POST['cantidad'] as $i => $cantidad) {
  $insertQuery[] = '(?, ?, ?)';
  $insertData[] = $_POST['cantidad'][$i];
  $insertData[] = $_POST['nombreProd'][$i];
  $insertData[] = $_POST['Id']; //OR $insertData[] = $_POST['Id'][0], depending on $_POST array
            }
```

Comment: Thank you Dan! the `$insertData[] = $_POST['Id'][0]` made it all work!, you save my day!. Best regards!